# SSRS parameter removes other filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a parameter called @branch set with a default of 'ALL', the default loads correctly, but when I select a specific branch all my other filters are removed.

```
 SELECT
      cust.no_
      ,cust.status
      ,cust.name
      ,cust.surname
      ,cust.addr1
      ,cust.addr2
      ,cust.pc
      ,cust.benefit
      ,cust.datenew
      ,cust.branch
      ,cust.rowno
      ,cust.pb
      ,cust.fimail
    FROM
      cust
    WHERE
      cust.status = N'active'
      AND cust.fimail NOT LIKE N'no'
      AND cust.benefit NOT IN('estate', 'internal', 'nonmemb', 'stf', 'student')
      AND (cust.datenew >= DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE()) AND cust.datenew < DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())))
    AND ('ALL' IN (@branch)) OR (cust.branch IN (@branch))

    order by datenew
```

here is my branch parameter query

```
SELECT
  branch.branch
FROM
  branch
UNION
SELECT 'ALL' as branch
```

in my parameter properties I don't allow for nulls, blanks or multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add extra () as bellow

```
AND (('ALL' IN (@branch)) OR (cust.branch IN (@branch)))
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! I knew it was something small I was missing I just couldn't see it